# How colon(:) works in python & pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I create a DataFrame：

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(1,11),'b':['m','f','m','m','m','f','m','f','f','f'],'c':np.random.randn(10)})
```

Which looks like：

```
    a  b         c
0   1  m  0.495439
1   2  f  1.444694
2   3  m  0.150637
3   4  m -1.078252
4   5  m  0.618045
5   6  f -0.525368
6   7  m  0.188912
7   8  f  0.159014
8   9  f  0.536495
9  10  f  0.874598
```

When I want to select some rows, I run

```
data[:2] or data.ix[2]
```

But when I try:

```
se = range(2)
data[se]
```

There's a error:

```
KeyError: 'No column(s) named: [0 1]'
```

I know DataFrame select a col as default.What happened when I run `data[se]`?
How colon(:) works in python?

Comment: Providing a list tries to select from the columns (and you do not have columns with name 0 or 1), while providing a slice like `:2` slices the rows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have never used Pandas but a good explanation of slicing (`[::]` notation in python can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation). Now from what I read in the [manual](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#slicing-ranges)

> With DataFrame, slicing inside of [] slices the rows. This is provided largely as a convenience since it is such a common operation.
>
> ```
> In [32]: df[:3]
> Out[32]: 
>                    A         B         C         D
> 2000-01-01 -0.282863  0.469112 -1.509059 -1.135632
> 2000-01-02 -0.173215  1.212112  0.119209 -1.044236
> 2000-01-03 -2.104569 -0.861849 -0.494929  1.071804
>
> In [33]: df[::-1]
> Out[33]: 
>                    A         B         C         D
> 2000-01-08 -1.157892 -0.370647 -1.344312  0.844885
> 2000-01-07  0.577046  0.404705 -1.715002 -1.039268
> 2000-01-06  0.113648 -0.673690 -1.478427  0.524988
> 2000-01-05  0.567020 -0.424972  0.276232 -1.087401
> 2000-01-04 -0.706771  0.721555 -1.039575  0.271860
> 2000-01-03 -2.104569 -0.861849 -0.494929  1.071804
> 2000-01-02 -0.173215  1.212112  0.119209 -1.044236
> 2000-01-01 -0.282863  0.469112 -1.509059 -1.135632
> ```

In your example where you use `range(2)` that gives you `[0, 1]` as *list*. What I think you need is `data[0:1]` to slice the `DataFrame` and get rows 0 and 1 which is the same as `data[:1]` omitting the zero. If you wanted for example rows 3,4 and 5 that would be `data[3:5]`.

Additionally, looking at some examples in the manual you can use *step*, so:

- `data[::2]` gives you every 2nd row
- `data[::-1]` returns all the rows in reverse order
- Combining ranges and step: `data[0:10:2]` will result in rows 0,2,4,6,8 and 10

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks.If I want to select these row [2,4,3,5,1],I run df[slice([2,4,3,5,1])],there is an error.I just used df.ix[2,4,3,5,1].Is there a different way to do that?

Comment: Do you need them in that order? You can only do a single range with `[]` and cannot change order other than skip rows or reverse (as far as I know). Doing `df[1:5]` should give you the rows that you need but not in the order you want...

Comment: However, when I do df[1:2] I only get row indexed 1, and not 1 and 2. What am I missing? [at least in other programming languages 1:2 means row (or column) 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

The [start:limit:step] syntax is known as slicing.
You can easily create an instance of a slice using the [slice()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) function:

> class slice(stop)
>
> class slice(start, stop[, step])
>
> Return a slice object representing the set of indices specified by
>   range(start, stop, step). The start and step arguments default to
>   None. Slice objects have read-only data attributes start, stop and
>   step which merely return the argument values (or their default). They
>   have no other explicit functionality; however they are used by
>   Numerical Python and other third party extensions. Slice objects are
>   also generated when extended indexing syntax is used. For example:
>   a[start:stop:step] or a[start:stop, i]. See itertools.islice() for an
>   alternate version that returns an iterator.

In your case, you could write something like this to return the first 2 rows

```
se = slice(None, 2)
data[se]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> data.ix[range(2)]
   a  b         c
0  1  m -0.323834
1  2  f  0.159787
```